# Javascript function to return true or false, if specific characters are present in an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this ...

```
[ "BA456", "CA456", "GA345", "BA234" ]
```

What I would like to do is write a function, if I  call it like this ...

> myfunction('BA', 'CA', 'GA', 'DA');

should return "True" if passed value present and "False" if absent. Expected output is shown below.

```
BA: T
CA: T
GA: T
DA: F
```

**What I have tried so far**

```
var arr = [ "BA456", "CA456", "GA345", "BA234" ]
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    if(arr[i].indexOf('BA') != -1)
    {
        console.log(arr[i]); // returns BA456, BA234
    }
}
```

I am looking for the most efficient way of doing this .... I am not sure if using `.indexOf` is the most efficient way of doing this ?

Hope someone can help.... Thanks in advance ...

Comment: `indexOf` is pretty fast already, you can use regex aswell, which is faster than `indexOf` as long as the `String` is not too long (eg 1 million  characters)

Comment: @Greggz why do you think regex is faster than `indexOf`?

Comment: Yes, `indexOf` is fine if you are looking for the search term anywhere in the string. However, in your examples the term is always at the start, in which case using [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) would be considerably faster.

Comment: @Bergi Performance benchmarks told me so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of an easier way:

```js
var arr = ["BA456", "CA456", "GA345", "BA234"];

// Function
function myfunction(...args) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
    result[i] = args[i] + ': ' + (arr[i].includes(args[i]) ? 'T' : 'F');
  return result.join('\n');
}

// Output
console.log(myfunction('BA', 'CA', 'GA', 'DA'));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think you should compare `arr[i]` only with `args[i]`

Comment: @Bergi Why not? That's what the OP wants!

Comment: I'm not so sure there. In their "*What I have tried so far*", they look for `BA` in every element of the array. That the example is ambiguous is unfortunate :-/

Comment: @Bergi In my understanding, the attempt with `BA` was only because they couldn't achieve to create a function like they said above and call it like this: `myfunction('BA', 'CA', 'GA', 'DA')`. So, this is what I did in my snippet. :)

Comment: Thanks @TakitIsy, You answer was simple and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using es6, something like this.

```
var arr = ["BA456", "CA456", "GA345", "BA234"];
function myfunction(...args) {
    return args.map(arg => arr.find(e => e.includes(arg)) ? 'T' : 'F');
}
myfunction('BA', 'CA', 'GA', 'DA');
```

Comment: Thanks @Hayk, I want it to work in as many browsers as possible so ES5 is preferred. What is the best ES5 equivalent ?

Comment: Change return of function to this. 

args.map(arg => arr.filter(e => e.indexOf(arg) != -1).shift() ? 'T' : 'F');

Comment: @HaykHakobyan and ditch the arrow function :-)

Comment: Thanks @HaykHakobyan, It seems like most ES6 features are well supported in most modern browsers these days.

Comment: @klaasman yeah, that result of test editing without compile ).

Answer (score -3):

```
You can try using regular expression like below

    var arr = [ "BA456", "CA456", "GA345", "BA234" ];
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        var patt = new RegExp('BA');
        if(patt.test(arr[i]))
        {            
            console.log(arr[i]); // returns BA456, BA234
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain why you think this is better than the original code